# How do I insert a variable entered into a textbox into a text string with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate a link

```
<a href="sms://[mobilenumber];body=exampletext">Send Sms/Text</a>
```

but need to have the user enter the [mobilenumber] into a separate textbox.

Comment: Do you know about how variables work?

Comment: At a basic level, yes.  An example script would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to answer this yourself easily if you learn Javascript first. Here is a little help:

Create a function in the javascript to update the number

```
function updateLink(number)
{
    var link = document.getElementById("link");
    link.href = "sms://" + number + ";body=exampletext";
    link.innerHTML = link.href;
}
```

With an HTML textbox and anchor with the `text` and `link` id.
The link updates every time a key is pressed, because the `updateLink` function triggers on the `onkeyup` event.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="updateLink(this.value)"></input>
<a href="#" id="link">sms://;body=exampletext</a>
```

Hope this helps you learn

Answer (score 0):

I create a JavaScript function you can use for this. You would alter your code so it looks like this:

```
<a class="link" href="#">Link text here</a>
```

then store your potential string in a variable like so:

```
var hrefString = "sms://{0};body={1}">Send Sms/Text";
```

Then use my stringInject function found here:

Github: https://github.com/tjcafferkey/stringinject

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringinject

Once you get the values you're dynamically inserting, you pass them into the function with the string like so:

```
hrefString = stringInject(hrefString, [phoneNumber, bodyText]);
```

then set hrefString as your href again

```
var link = document.querySelector('.link');
link.href = hrefString;
```